# impresión en orden ascendente y descendente

Tags: dev-c++

Buenas quisiera saber como mostrar los números de forma ascendente y descendente de 1 al 50 solo números impares, tiene que contener una array solo llevo la parte de manera ascendente y después de llegar al 50 imprime números mayores y no los de forma descendente.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
int a, array[50];
cout<<"Numeros en Forma ASCENDENTE"<<endl;
for (a=1; a<=50; a++)
{
    if(a % 2 == 1)  
    cout<< a <<endl;
}
{
array[a]=a;
}
for (a=1; a<=50; a++)
{
printf("%d\n",array[a]);
}
cout<<"Numeros en Forma DESCENDENTE"<<endl;
for (a=1; a<=50; a--){
array[a]=a;
}
for (a=1; a<=50; a--){
printf("%d\n",array[a]);
}
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes tu condición para los descendientes al revés, sería

```
for(a = 50; a >= 1; i--)
```

Si quieres hacerlo descendente no puedes decirle que empiece en 1 y termine en <= 50, no tiene sentido, siempre tienes que ir del mayor al menor

Espero haberte ayudado